# How to optimally handle sql connections in vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, try-catch

**ASP.NET WEB PROGRAMMING**

How to optimally handle

- Open
- Close
- Dispose
- Exception

when retrieving data from a database.

**LOOKING TO OPTIMISE**

I have always used the following to make a connection, catch any errors, and then correctly dispose of the connection in either event.

**VB.NET**

```
Try
  con.Open()
  //...
  con.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
  lbl.Text = ex.Message
Finally
  If con IsNot Nothing Then
    con.Dispose()
  End If
End Try
```

After reading many articles I find people practically throwing up at this code; however, I do not see any other way to accomodate the four steps required **efficiently**.

The alternative, and I believe more cpu friendly **`USING`** statement, seems to be the tool of choice for the correct disposal of a sql connection. But what happens when bad data is retrieved from the database and there is nothing in place to indicate to an end user what went wrong?

**QUESTION**

Between: **Using**, **try catch**, and **other**.

Which is faster, cleaner, and/or most efficient way to handle a data retrieval statement?

*I am happy to hear people's opinions but I am looking for facts.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use the following block of code as template. It combines the Using...End Using and Try...Catch blocks.

```
Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.SQLConn)
    Try
        Conn.open
    Catch ex As SqlException

    End Try    
End Using
```

There is no need to call `conn.Dispose()` because using block does that automatically.

Comment: So I have heard many time before but this seems redundant to me. As using is compiled as try/catch anyway. Nesting try/catch in using seems like bad code. Surely adding con.close in finally block is more efficient than wrapping try/catch in a using block?

Comment: Good points. Also I think try/catch is good because you get chance to handle the exception and do the necessary logging/cleanup steps. I will do more research and update if I have new info.

Answer (score 0):

Use Entity Framework, it implements Unit Of Work Pattern for You efficiently, and perform your operations within transaction scope

Answer (score 0):

Always use the "Using" process as it will automatically assign and then free up system resources.  You are still able to perform the try-catch within this to present errors to the user.

Comment: So I have heard many time before but this seems redundant to me. As using is compiled as try/catch anyway. Nesting try/catch in using seems like bad code. Surely adding con.close in finally block is more efficient than wrapping try/catch in a using block?

Comment: A try...finally is acceptable inside of Using. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx